# google htmlservice - passing form object to library function comes as udefined

Tags: javascript, html

I try to use google sites' HtmlService to pass form object from an html file to a library file - which comes off as undefined.
my html file is also in the same library:

```
<script>
  function AlertUser(message) 
  {
    alert ( message );
  }
</script>
<? var betType = GetBetsType(); ?>
<? if( VerifyTimesUp( betType ) == false ) { ?>
  <? var curRound = getCurrentRoundObj(); ?>
  <h> <?= curRound.roundName ?> round <?= curRound.roundNumber ?> Bets: <br><br></h>
  <? var betsData = GetBetsData( betType ); ?>
  <? var firstGameNumber = 1 + (curRound.roundNumber - 1)*curRound.fixtureNumber; ?>
  <? var lastGameNumber  = firstGameNumber + curRound.fixtureNumber; ?>
  <form id="myForm1">
  <? for (var i = firstGameNumber; i < lastGameNumber; i++) { ?>       
    <p style="text-align:left;"> Game <?=(i-firstGameNumber+1) ?>: <?=  betsData[i][2] ?> vs  <?= betsData[i][3] ?>
     <input name="homeResult<?i?>" type="text" style="float:right" />
     <input name="awayResult<?i?>" type="text" style="float:right" /> <br><br>
    </p>
  <? } ?> 
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" 
      onclick="google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(AlertUser)
        .ProcessForm(this.form);"/>
       </form> 
    <? } ?>
```

Process Form function is defined in my non-library function:

```
function doGet() 
{
  siteFunctions.UpdateBetsType('GroupStage');
   return siteFunctions.CreateHTMLBetsTemplate()
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
}

function ProcessForm(formObject)
{
  return siteFunctions.GeneralProcessForm(formObject);
}
```

And my library code is as follows:

```
function CreateHTMLBetsTemplate()
{
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('BetsTemplateHTML');
}

function UpdateBetsType( newBetsType )
{
  curBetType = newBetsType;
}

function GetBetsType()
{
  return curBetType;
}
function GeneralProcessForm(formObject)
{
  var roundObj        = getCurrentRoundObj();
  var firstGameNumber = 1 + (roundObj.roundNumber - 1)*roundObj.fixtureNumber;
  var lastGameNumber  = firstGameNumber + roundObj.fixtureNumber;
  for( var i=firstGameNumber; i<=lastGameNumber; i++ )
  {
    eval( 'var curInput = formObject.homeResult' +i);
    if( (curInput == '') || (curInput.toString() != curInput) ) 
      return ('Invalid Bet: Home result in game ' + (i-firstGameNumber+1) + 'is not a valid number');
  }
}
```

In the GeneralProcessForm function i get the formObject to be undefined.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: In the "onclick" part in the HTML i send ProcessForm(this.parentNode) and not ProcessForm(this.form) as mentioned (this.form doesn't work).